# Making unique field validation while updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to validate for the unique record While editing but it always displays the field must be unique. basically i need to ignore the value of that id. id is the primary key.

```
$validator=Validator::make($request->all(),[
'name'=>'required',
'telephone'=>'required|unique:telephone',
'email'=>'unique:telephone',
'altemail'=>'unique:telephone',
'image'=>'image',

]);

if($validator->fails()){
return redirect('/telephone/addview')
    ->withErrors($validator);   
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use additional arguments for [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique) rule

```
$validator=Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'name'=>'required',
    'telephone'=>'required|unique:telephone,telephone,'.$yourMdelInstance->id,
    'email'=>'unique:telephone,email,'.$yourMdelInstance->id,
    'altemail'=>'unique:telephone,altemail,'.$yourMdelInstance->id,
    'image'=>'image',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique) you can exclude a value in your unique validation.

Example:

```
// YourController.php

publiuc function postUpdate(Request $request)
{

    // Get your resource first.
    $model = Model::find($request->input('id'));

    // Check if exists
    if (!$model) \App::abort(404);


    // Validate
    $this->validate($request, [
        '...'
        'telephone' => 'required|unique:yourtablename,telephone,'.$model->telephone,
        '...'
    ]);

}
```